# Why does MRO sometimes "stall" in parallel applications?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have been attempting to optimise a Bioconductor package for parallel processing. In doing so I have encountered two bits of code which run fine in serial, but using `mclapply`, the processes stall (0% CPU & disk usage) but never actually fail or error out.

One is multiplication of an arma/armadillo matrix and a vector, for which I cannot yet get a minimal working reprex. I have included a reprex for the other below (taking eigenvalues/vectors of a matrix). Interestingly, running the code with the `doParallel` seems to work fine.

```r
library("parallel")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")

m <- diag(100)
eigen(m)
lapply(1:10, function(i) eigen(m))
mclapply(1:10, function(i) eigen(m))

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% eigen(m)
```

This is due to MRO's use of BLAS libraries, which are multi-threaded.

Comment: 1. The task in your example is not slow enough to benefit from parallelization (due to overhead). 2. I cannot reproduce the problem. Please provide your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Moreover, for matrix operations, you don't want to parallelize them yourself. You'll gain more by using an optimized parallel math library such as Microsoft R Open (MRO) and OpenBLAS.

Comment: It is a minimal working example. The intention is not to demonstrate the benefits of parallel code. The code being run is much more complex (Bayesian inference via MCMC) so parallelising in this manner is very much the right way to do things. 

Thanks for mentioning MRO. I am running MRO and the issue seems to be the MKLthreads setting. `setMKLthreads(1)` resolves this issue.

Comment: I'll assume the problematic code is *not* what's in the example: It could be that you're trying to parallelize code that can *not* be parallelized because it relies on non-exportable/non-parallelizable objects, e.g. file or DBI connection, xml2 objects, etc.  See Section 'Non-exportable objects' in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html for examples (the problem is there regardless on the parallel framework you use)

Comment: If you use *foreach*, you can test for non-exportable objects by first replacing `registerDoParallel(cl)` with `doFuture::registerDoFuture(); future::plan(cluster, workers = cl)`.  Then, by setting `options(future.globals.onReference = "error")` (comes with some overhead), the future framework will look for non-exportable objects and give you an informative error if those are used.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, the problem is (I think) that the multi-threaded BLAS/Lapack libraries in MRO do not handle parallelisation in some scenarios. I suspect what happens is that objects in memory aren't duplicated for each thread.

Comment: If you run the mclapply above using Microsoft R Open, it will stall at 0% CPU usage, so yes the problematic code is in the example.

Comment: You should mention that you use MRO in the question. It appears that you are trying to parallelize code that is parallelized internally (via the BLAS). That is crucial information.

Comment: I realised this only after F Prive mentioned it. It is largely pointless updating the question as I now know the answer.

Comment: Well, then delete the question.

Comment: I have updated the question; I'll keep it here in case anyone runs into the same issue.